# How can i do if some one press read more button it ask for login in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i am new to wordpress, now only i started learning wordpress, i developed one website in wordpress using a theme.

in my site i have read more button, now my client asking if some one press read more button it ask for login and after login only the rest of the contents visible to the users.

i dont know how to do it in wordpress.

is theire any plugins available for this or how to develop a code for this

please help me .

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO isn't a code writing service, you need to make an effort to do this yourself.

Comment: This plugin might help: [Theme my Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/)

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what kind of login you would need. In the publish settings of a post or page (the box with the publish button in it), you can change the visibility to private, then choose a password one needs to enter to view the contents. All one needs to view the content is this single password, no need for a wordpress user.

Alternatively, if you require your visitors to have a wordpress user to be able to login and view the content, you could use this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/pagerestrict/

Comment: Thank you Thomas,    my client asking if some users visited to my website and he want to read the content then that pericular page ask for register into our site then only its visible to that user

Comment: Then I think you should try the plugin!